# How to hide border in react-chart-js-2

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js, linechart

I am facing a rather troublesome problem with chart as follows:

- I want to remove the outermost border and keep the inner lines, but the chart doesn't allow me to do that. I tried using 'drawBorder: false', but it still doesn't work. Is there any way to handle this?
- How to remove the value of the origin x-Axis and Y-Axis?
  please refer to the image
- How to edit the value of A-Xis? I want it to increase by 1000 each time on the X-Axis.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SEVFv.jpg)

Answer (score 4):

Setting the `scales` option like this:

```js
scales: {
    y: {
      grid: {
        drawBorder: false, // <-- this removes y-axis line
        lineWidth: function (context) {
          return context?.index === 0 ? 0 : 1; // <-- this removes the base line
        }
      }
    },
    x: {
      grid: {
        drawBorder: false,
        lineWidth: 0 // <-- this removes vertical lines between bars
      }
    }
  }
```

should achieve the desired look. Check out [this code sandbox with an example](https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-sun-hkhsvj?file=/App.tsx:504-878).

You can find more information about styling the chart [here](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/styling.html#grid-line-configuration).

Comment: Thanks your spending time helping me.